# Creating a network in UTM

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, utm

I am trying to create a polygon from machines such as Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, and for this I took a ready-made template - https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/windows-xp 
But I ran into a problem - how to create subnets, for example, as in VMware (VMNet1,VMnet2...) to connect my machines? (M1 Mac OS Sonoma)

I tried to create a guest network, but it seems to me that this is a bad option.